# Sum specific data

Tags: eloquent, laravel-8

[I Have this table for bills. In bills I have field call amount_left. Whenever I add a new record this field got update. Now I need to calculate outstanding but the problem is I have to sum only latest records of all individual property_id. How to do that?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRUMd.png)

Comment: what is property_id?

Comment: @ElioBteich property_id is the foreign key. All bills are created against individual property. In the table you will see property_id as foreign key. I have attached the photo of my table.

Comment: i know that it's a foreign key man, but i need to see the property table to be able to understand the task!